# php preg_match_all brackets

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm stuck with a bit of php code, I am getting information of a site which has information inside brackets, the problem is I only want the information infront of the brackets, since the content of the brackets can be anything I am confused what to do...

```
preg_match_all('/<title>FlightAware >(.*?) <\/title>/ms', $title, $airports, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

this is what I have the actual title is: FlightAware > London Heathrow Airport (London, England) EGLL / LHR Flug-Tracker

All I would like from that is the "London Heathrow Airport"... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's stored as

```
<title>FlightAware > London Heathrow Airport (London, England) EGLL / LHR Flug-Tacker</title>
```

You could try

```
/<title>FlightAware > (.+?) \((.+?)\)(.+?)<\/title>/ms
```

Which should give you just `London Heathrow Airport`. You'll have `London, England` in the second match parameter, and `EGLL / LHR Flug Tracker-` in the third match parameter. Granted, this is only if that is the EXACT format each one is stored in.

Also, work on your accept rating.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/<title>FlightAware >(.*)\(.+\).+<\/title>/ms', $title, $airports, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```